# Confilict Interface Implementing in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I want to implement Interface method and after implement all method in my class,I have an error that please implement all method,my interface is:

```
public interface IAccountRepository
{
    Task<IAccount> AuthenticateAsync(string username, string password);
    Task<IAccount> RegisterAsync(string username, string password,AccountType accountType);
}
```

and my class that wants to implement is:

```
public class AccountRepository : IAccountRepository
{
    public Task<IAccount> AuthenticateAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        ISession session = null;
        Task<Mabna.AccountsSDK.IAccount> objAccount;
        var objAccountsSdk = new Mabna.AccountsSDK.Client(session);
        objAccountsSdk.AccountManager.AuthenticateAsync(username, password);
        return null;
    }

    public Task<IAccount> RegisterAsync(string username, string password, AccountType accounttype)
    {
        ISession session = null;
        Task<Mabna.AccountsSDK.IAccount> objAccount;
        var objAccountsSdk = new Mabna.AccountsSDK.Client(session);
        objAccountsSdk.AccountManager.RegisterAsync(username, password,accounttype);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that it is this interface/implementation that is causing the error and not IAccount?

Comment: @Saeed Py: I do not see any problem with the Interface implementation. can you please post the error message that you get. so that we can workout on it.

Comment: Have you included all the necessary namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

(Preface: I don't think this usually causes implementation errors), your `accountType` variable is cased different on your interface and your class.  Your class has it as `accounttype` *Note the t is not capital in the class*

Outside of the casing, everything else looks to be legitimate.  Are you 100% sure that you are recieving this error on this interface and not IAccount or ISession?

And as a side note, why do your methods have a return type of `Task<IAccount>` when you are clearly always returning null?  Why not make these `void` methods?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like RegisterAsync is not implemented
you did implement RegisterAsync1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public interface IAccountRepository
{
    Task AuthenticateAsync(string username, string password);
    Task RegisterAsync(string username, string password,AccountType accountType);
}
```

Since you are not returning a value use task instead:

```
public class AccountRepository : IAccountRepository
{
    public async Task AuthenticateAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        ISession session = null;
        Task<Mabna.AccountsSDK.IAccount> objAccount;
        var objAccountsSdk = new Mabna.AccountsSDK.Client(session);
        await objAccountsSdk.AccountManager.AuthenticateAsync(username, password);
    }

    public async Task RegisterAsync(string username, string password, AccountType accounttype)
    {
        ISession session = null;
        Task<Mabna.AccountsSDK.IAccount> objAccount;
        var objAccountsSdk = new Mabna.AccountsSDK.Client(session);
        await objAccountsSdk.AccountManager.RegisterAsync(username, password,accounttype);
    }
}
```